# bkde2D of KernSmooth results in "'F_lbtwod' not found"

Tags: r, kernel-density

Running the example

```
data(geyser, package="MASS")
x <- cbind(geyser$duration, geyser$waiting)
est <- bkde2D(x, bandwidth=c(0.7, 7))
contour(est$x1, est$x2, est$fhat)
persp(est$fhat)
```

results in the error

> Error in linbin2D(x, gpoints1, gpoints2) : Object 'F_lbtwod' not found

at the line `est <- bkde2D(x, bandwidth=c(0.7, 7))`.

Why is that? What do I need to do to get it working?

I am using KernSmooth version 2.23-15.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=de_DE.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=de_DE.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.3 tools_3.4.3
```

Comment: Using `library(MASS)
library(KernSmooth)` your code works fine for me ..

Comment: @MrSmithGoesToWashington: I updated where I got the error, so it is not about the data and I loaded the library KernSmooth, otherwise I would have gotten a different error.

Comment: What version of `KernSmooth` and `R` do you have ?

Comment: @MrSmithGoesToWashington: Updated the question: I am using KernSmooth version 2.23-15.

Comment: Same version for me .. could you add the results of `sessionInfo()` ?

Comment: @MrSmithGoesToWashington: Done.